# Writing a rather obtuse JSON query using Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I am looking to translate an SQL query (Postgres) into Scala Slick code for use in my Play application.

The data looks something like this:

```
parent_id | json_column
----------+-----------------------------------------
          | [ {"id": "abcde-12345", "data": "..."}
2         | , {"id": "67890-fghij", "data": "..."}
          | , {"id": "klmno-00000", "data": "..."} ]
```

Here's my query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM
    table1 t1,
    json_array_elements(t1.json_column) e,
    json_to_record(e.value) AS r("id" text, data text)
  WHERE
    "id" = 'abcde-12345'
    AND t1.parent_id = 2
);
```

This finds the results I need; any objects in t1 that include a "row" in the json_column array that has the id of "abcde-12345".  The "parent_id" and "id" will be passed in to this query via query parameters (both Strings).

How would I write this query in Scala using Slick?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Ha, thx, I'll reword to include the question

Comment: easiest - maybe laziest? - way is probably to just use plain sql .. `sql""" [query] """.as[ (type1,type2..) ]`  , using the $var notation for the variables

Comment: Did that work for you, or how did you solve it? Otherwise you can use `SimpleFunction` to map the json calls

Comment: I ended up just using plain sql as you said.  I had that already, but thought it felt like a code smell, but in this code base there are LOTS of other raw SQL queries, so it's not out of place.  If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it, if you're into the whole SO points thing. ;-)   Thanks @Ossip!

Comment: ok. don't really about the points, but always good to resolve a question. the simplefunction mapping for the functions would be easy but I never tried it where it produces multiple values / needs a sub-query like you have in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest - maybe laziest? - way is probably to just use plain sql ..

```
sql"""[query]""".as[ (type1,type2..) ]
```

using the `$var` notation for the variables.

Otherwise you can use `SimpleFunction` to map the json calls, but I'm not quite sure how that works when they generate multiple results per row. Seems that might get complicated..